# C# Managed Code optimization

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I have a managed C++ DLL that I use in my C# Application. The DLL is processing a lot of images (thousands) and using OCR to extract the text from it; Even though I know that OCR Processing consumes a lot of CPU, I was wondering if it is possible to optimize the code for better performance.

Currently it takes one minute to parse approx. 15 pages PNG pages. I would to get down to around 30-40 seconds.

**The C++ Code:**

```
        char* OCRWrapper::GetUTF8Text(char* path, char* lang, char* imgPath)
        {
            char* imageText;
            tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();

            if (api->Init(path, lang)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract. Incorrect datapath or incorrect lanauge\n"); /*This should throw an error to the caller*/
                exit(1);
            }

            /*Open a reference to the imagepath*/
            Pix *image = pixRead(imgPath);

            /*Read the image object;*/
            api->SetImage(image);

            // Get OCR result
            imageText = api->GetUTF8Text();

            /*writeToFile(outText);*/
            /*printf("OCR output:\n%s", imageText);*/

            /*Destroy the text*/
            api->End();

            pixDestroy(&image);
            /*std::string x = std::string(imageText);*/

            return imageText;
        }
```

The C# method that creates an instance of OCROBject class. The OCRObject is the class actually calling the DLL, see below this method.

```
  private void GetTextFromSavedImages(List<string> imagesPath)
    {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder allPagesText = new StringBuilder();
            OCRObject ocr = new OCRObject(this.dbHandler.GetApplicationSetting(this.m_ProfileName, "TesseractLanguage").ApplicationSettingValue, this.dbHandler.GetApplicationSetting(this.m_ProfileName, "TesseractConfigurationDataPath").ApplicationSettingValue); //Settings.Default.TesseractConfigurationDataPath
            for (int i = 0; i < imagesPath.Count; i++)
            {

                string pageText = ocr.GetOCRText(imagesPath[i]);
                this.m_pdfDictionary.Add(i + 1, pageText);
                allPagesText.Append(pageText);
            }
            this.AllPageText = allPagesText.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log(ex.ToString(), LogInformationType.Error);
        }
    }
```

And finally the OcrObject Class:

```
public class OCRObject
        {
            private string m_tessLanguage;
            private string m_tessConfPath;
            [DllImport(@"\OCR\OCR.dll", EntryPoint = "GetUTF8Text", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
            private static extern IntPtr GetUTF8Text(string path, string lang, string imgPath);

            public OCRObject(string language, string tessConfPath)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(language))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Tesseract language is null or empty.");
                }
                if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(tessConfPath))
                {
                    throw new DirectoryNotFoundException("Could not find directory => " + tessConfPath);
                }    
                this.m_tessLanguage = language;
                this.m_tessConfPath = tessConfPath;
            }    
            public string GetOCRText(string imagePath)
            {
                return this.StringFromNativeUtf8(GetUTF8Text(this.m_tessConfPath, this.m_tessLanguage, imagePath));
            }

            private string StringFromNativeUtf8(IntPtr nativeUtf8)
            {
                try
                {
                    int len = 0;
                    if (nativeUtf8 == IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        return string.Empty;
                    }
                    while (Marshal.ReadByte(nativeUtf8, len) != 0) ++len;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
                    Marshal.Copy(nativeUtf8, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    //GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Optimized); /*If this help???*/
                    string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
                    return text;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return string.Empty;
                }
            }
        }
```

Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Have you profiled the code to determine where your bottleneck is?  If so, where is most of your time being spent?

Comment: Yes, it's probably possible.  No, I am not going to do it for you.  You don't even have any requirements here. How fast is "fast enough"?

Comment: @DanBryant: How do I do that? I don't really know.

Comment: @EdS.: I have updated the question. Hope that helps.

Comment: You may want to pass the list of files to the C++ library so that you don't need to switch between managed and unmanaged code 'thousands' of times. It may be completely insubstancial, though. You should always measure before you optimise, humans are terrible at guessing in this case.

Comment: @JohnJackson, the term you want to research is "performance profiling".  There are a wide range of tools available that can help to automate this process.  You can also get some of the data manually by adding your own code to log elapsed times during execution at various points along the way.

Comment: @kamilk: I've thought about that but then I need to parse the root directory and then parse all of the images in C++ and then return a very very big list of text containing the pagetext along with the filename. This was even worse in performance.

Comment: Knowing the total time does not say much, you should measure the different stages of process execution. Only with granular measurements you will know where your bottlenecks and hence improve. Enter measuring points distributed in their code and locate points of higher cost of first processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Tesseract FAQ](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/FAQ#can-i-increase-speed-of-ocr) suggested that people run its executable in parallel (i.e. implying that it's single-threaded).

You could maybe try using `Parallel.For` to replace your `for` loop, and see if you can get a quick and dirty win out of it.

Edit: They've moved to GitHub, and the new FAQ suggested that

> You will get better results having Tesseract produce one page PDF
>   files in parallel, then splicing them together at the end

Comment: Thanks, that improved the performance a lot.

Comment: Which one? The parallel for, or the PDF trick?

Comment: I added a Parallel.ForEach instead of the loop to extract the text much faster.  I haven't tried the PDF part since I don't want Tesseract to produce PDF Pages as I already have the PDF.